# Showing that the identity $(j + k)^2 = j^2 + k^2$ is wrong.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> “For all numbers $j$ and $k$, $(j + k)^2 = j^2 + k^2$.”

How would you prove this is wrong??

When I times out the bracket with the number it makes $j^2 + k^2$ but that's wrong.

Should I put a number for $j$ and $k$ and then times it out?

Comment: Are your "2" supposed to be exponents, ie. $(j+k)^2 = j^2 + k^2$?

Comment: What is $j2$? You can format math on this site by following the instructions [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: j2 is to j2 ... I don't know?

Comment: @HonkyHanka try to clear (edit) the question so that someone could help you

Comment: I don't know how to and the instructions don't help me much!!!!The 2's are squared...

Answer (score 6):

Oh ok, well I think I've got a way of prooving it. I'm going to add a number for each letter  j and k...

$j = 1$

$k = 2$

$(j+k)^2=j^2+k^2$

$(2 + 1)^2 = 3^2 =9$ and $j^2 + k^2 = 1^2 + 2^2 = 1 + 4 = 5$ and $5$ isn't equal to $9$!

Comment: A counterexample like this is a fine way to show the equation is invalid.

Comment: Almost any time you have a statement beginning “for all *j*, *k*, …” or similar, and you’re asked to disprove it, the best way is to give a specific counterexample, some specific *j* and *k* for which the equation isn’t true.

Answer (score 3):

We develop this product term by term
$$(j+k)^2=(j+k)\times(j+k)=(j\times j)+\underbrace{(j\times k)+(k\times j)}_{=2\times j\times k}+(k\times k)$$
Therefore, we find this identity that you must learn by heart:
$$(j+k)^2=j^2+2jk+k^2$$
hence you can see that $$(j+k)^2=j^2+\underbrace{2jk}_{\text{a term more}}+k^2\neq j^2+k^2\quad\text{unless}\quad 2jk=0\quad\text{i.e unless}\quad j=0\,\text{or}\, k=0 $$

Answer (score 1):

$(j + k)^2$

If $j = 3$ and $k = 2$

= $(3+2)^2$

= $(3+2)(3+2)$

= $9+6+6+4$

= $25$

However, if we were to say that

$(j+k)^2=j^2+k^2$

then:

= $3^2+2^2$

= $9+4$

= 13

Which means that $(j + k)^2 \neq 3^2+2^2$