# How Do You Expand and Simplify?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do you expand and simplify $(x + 2y)^2$ or $(7x + 5y)^2$. I don't understand, how would you multiply that by itself?

I mean I can simplify and expand two brackets; e.g. $(x + 3) (x + 5)$ but I'm not sure how to do one bracket with a squared.

Comment: I know a x a = a^2 and x times x equals x^2.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389416/proof-an-equation-is-wrong/389521#389521  check your previous question answer given by sami ben

Comment: do you realize that FOIL is just an acronym for the "Distributive Property"? e.g. $(x+3)(x+5) = (x+3)x + (x+3)5 = (x^2+3x)+(5x+3\cdot 5) = x^2 + (3+5)x + 3\cdot 5$

Answer (score 5):

Another example:

$$(7x + 5y)^2 \;\; = \;\;(7x + 5y)(7x + 5y)$$

So just expand (distribute) as you normally would:

$$\begin{align}(7x + 5y)^2 & = (7x + 5y)(7x + 5y)\\ \\
& = 7x(7x + 5y) + 5y(7x + 5y) \\ \\
& = 49x^2 + 35 xy + 35 xy + 25 y^2 \\ \\
& = 49x^2 + 70 xy + 25 y^2
\end{align}$$

Comment: I just try to avoid insisting on the "FOIL" acronym; appealing to the distributive property is more generalizable!

Comment: I agree and I wish we could foil FOIL! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Recall that squaring something just means multiplying it by itself.
So $(x+2y)^2 = (x+2y)(x+2y)$

Comment: Ok, so for $(7x + 5y)^2$ it wouldn't be $(7x + 5y)$ $(7x + 5y)$ would it?

Comment: Yes, it would be, HonkyHanka.

Comment: Yes and $(x+2y)^3 = (x+2y)(x+2y)(x+2y)$ etc.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know that $a^2=a\times a$?

Furthermore you should know this equality
$$(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$$
hence in your case we have
$$(x+2y)^2=x^2+(2\times x\times(2y))+(2y)^2=x^2+4xy+4y^2$$

Answer (score 1):

Try this: $(x+2y)^2=(x+2y)(x+2y)$

Answer (score 0):

Expand, distribute, simplify.

$$(x+2y)^2=(x+2y)(x+2y)=x^2+2xy+2xy+4y^2=\boxed{x^2+4xy+4y^2}$$

$$(7x+5y)^2=(7x+5y)(7x+5y)=49x^2+35xy+35xy+25y^2=\boxed{49x^2+70xy+25y^2}$$